# Error: field may not be used in this type of formula

Tags: formula

[image: Error as shown in image link]

Hello Salesforce Community.

I have an issue with this message (Error: Field Select_VAT__c may not be used in this type of formula). I'm trying to get a value from selected field type picklist to another field type of percentage. Anyone could solve this? Thanks in advance.

Code as shown below.

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Select_VAT__c,"NO VAT"),0,10)
```

Comment: use a before save flow

Answer (score 0):

I hope Select_VAT__c is the field on the object which you are creating the percentage field.

As per the considerations  for default values [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_default_field_value_considerations.htm&type=5)

> Since the default value is inserted before users enter any values in the new record, you cannot use the fields on the current record to create a default field value.

Comment: Hello @SaiPraveen Kakkirala, In this case Select_VAT__c is the field of picklist. I'm trying to use `IF(ISPICKVAL(Select_VAT__c,"NO VAT"),0,10)` formula in another field called VAT__c of percent type, when the condition NO VAT true it's returning 0 to VAT__c, otherwise is 10, but unfortunately an error message has occurred like **Field Select_VAT__c may not be used in this type of formula**. Thanks

Comment: There is another way to convert Select_VAT__c to formula? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the field to be editable by users or just formula field?